# How to fetch a emp first login and filter who's login time > 09:45:00 of every day of each emp

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-table

The table data I'm getting from database and I need to get only time which is greater than 9:45:00
[Table Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Bw7.png)

So How to sort or filter the time which is less than 9:45:00 am
which is time less than 9:45 should be in hidden.

```
SELECT UserId,employees.EmployeeName as name, MIN(LogDate) as FirstLogin 
                FROM devicelogs_processed 
                LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.EmployeeCode = devicelogs_processed.UserId 
                WHERE '$empId'= UserId AND LogDate BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31' 
                GROUP BY UserId, YEAR(LogDate), MONTH(LogDate), DAY(LogDate) 
                ORDER BY `FirstLogin` DESC
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Post your code/attempt, example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that was recommended to you when you registered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql function time(), extracts the time part from a given time/datetime expression, and add to your query TIME(LogDate) > '9:45:00'

```
SELECT UserId,employees.EmployeeName as name, MIN(LogDate) as FirstLogin 
                FROM devicelogs_processed 
                LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.EmployeeCode = devicelogs_processed.UserId 
                WHERE '$empId'= UserId AND LogDate BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31' and TIME(LogDate) > '9:45:00'
                GROUP BY UserId, YEAR(LogDate), MONTH(LogDate), DAY(LogDate) 
                ORDER BY `FirstLogin` DESC
```

Comment: how get only first entry of everyday, because it to login table for 1 users there will be multiple entry's. So iam getting 2 nd entry after 9:45

Comment: I want to fetch only lateComers from that table

Comment: TIME(LogDate) >= '9:45:00'

Comment: sry its not working

Comment: i'll give you one example personA logged in 9:00am and again 10:30 logged in with the above query its taking that 2nd log.

Comment: TIME(LogDate) <= '9:45:00' - this will give you all logins before the time if any